# Fancyhdr does not apply same header/footer on chapter and non-chapter pages

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a problem with the `fancy` package: I use the `report` documentclass and I have a chapter, a lot of text and then a new page starting with a section (or the next page has no chapter starting on that particular page).

The problem be, that what I defined for my header and footer is NOT on the chapter-page but only on the non-chapter page.
How come? What did I miss?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for use of \pageref{LastPage}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
\fancyhf{} %Clear header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage of \pageref{LastPage}} %Custom footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %Line at the header visible
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}} %Line at the footer visible

\title{A short example}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\chapter{A chapter}
Look at the footer

\newpage
\section{A section}
Look at the footer

\end{document}
```

Take notice: No line on page 2 at the bottom - a line on page 3 at the bottom.

Any clues?

Comment: In general one doesn't want headers in a chapter starting page: there's no need for them; moreover this will give a more distinctive look to those pages. In particular a rule above the chapter title doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can redefine the `plain` style that's issued by `\chapter`. Here's how you can do; I'd recommend not having headings in the chapter starting pages, nor the upper rule.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for use of \pageref{LastPage}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
\title{A short example}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\chapter{A chapter}
Look at the footer

\newpage
\section{A section}
Look at the footer

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg--so this means that since \pagestyle changes before the chapter--it should affect the chapter also--am i right?? now if i comment out the line regarding \fancyfoot--the fancyfoot still appears in the chapter--why??

Comment: @jsbibra I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: \pagestyle{iha fancy style }------is mentioned just before chapter start--so will this command affect all following pages such as chapter and section---------or will this command only affect the toc and title page??

Comment: also kindly advise me if there is a particular method outlined somewhere for coding and typesetting------for example the beginsection should be indented once and the next line should be indented twice and for tables should have 4 inndentations and so on-------or are the indents are as per individual choice-----just want to make the coding /typesetting more neat ---------as in the image added

Answer (score 52):

For the `report` document class, the command `\chapter` is defined in the file `report.cls`, starting on line 339 or so. Contained in the definition of the `\chapter` macro is the instruction `\thispagestyle{plain}`, instructing LaTeX to set the chapter's first page in the so-called "plain" style.

To switch the page style of the first page of a chapter from "plain" to "fancy", you could load the `etoolbox` package and patch the definition of the `\chapter` macro:

```
\documentclass{report}
% other preamble stuff...
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
% rest of document ...
```

Comment: +1, very useful. This also works for the `book` document class.

Comment: What about book with different style for even/odd pages?

Comment: @KcFnMi - Not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to find out if the `book` document class inserts the instruction `\thispagestyle{plain}` on pages with part- and chapter-level headers? If so, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Not sure I understand it. Though asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493945/how-to-set-fancyhdr-on-chapter-initial-page-of-two-side-report. Comment/answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: also kindly advise me if there is a particular method outlined somewhere for coding and typesetting------for example the beginsection should be indented once and the next line should be indented twice and for tables should have 4 inndentations and so on-------or are the indents are as per individual choice-----just want to make the coding /typesetting more neat ---------as in the image added

Comment: @jsbibra - TeX imposes very few restrictions on input formatting. One restriction I'm aware of -- which, in my opinion, is not much of a restriction at all -- is that *comments* run from the `%` character until the end of the line; there are no block comments and no multiline comments, unlike many (most?) other programming languages. Thus, how TeX and LaTeX input should be formatted is almost entirely a matter of personal preference. Some packages which deal with verbatim-like material *do* impose some (generally very mild) restrictions on where certain input elements must be placed.