# make all pages with the same style footer

Tags: header-footer, lyx

I use Lyx 2.1.
I want to make all pages with the same style footer.
The first page of each chapter has its own style (Style No. 1)
Other pages have a different style (Style No. 2)
is it possible to make all pages with (Style No. 2)?

class document: report

(Style No. 1 ):
[image]

(Style No. 2) :
[image]

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: You can probably use this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117334/586 (replacing `fancy` with whatever the name of Style No. 2 is).

Comment: Report. to report all pages must have the same style footer or the first page of the chapter should have its own style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put into the preamble (`Document->Preferences->Preamble`)

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@headings
```

if you are using the pagestyle fancy then write

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
```

or define `\fancypagestyle{plain}{<settings>}` See documentation of package `fancyhdr`. The pagestyle for the *first* page of a chapter is preset to `plain`.

Comment: Thank you. just question : to report all pages must have the same style footer or the first page of the chapter should have its own style?

Comment: From typographers view: the _first_ page of a _chapter_  should be different. No header only a pagenumber in the footer.

Comment: so style footer of the first must be like other pages or not?

Comment: As I already wrote: "it should be different and _not_ the same.

Comment: @user1936895 Besides that a header detracts the title, think for a second what the hell you need this on the first page of the chapter. The title of huge letters is not enough information about where you are in the document?