# headings and footnotes in first page different

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I want that the first page of each chapter has no headrule. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{afterpage}


  \begin{document}
  \pagestyle{plain}

\markboth{}{}   
\chapter{In}
\vspace{-50pt}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}

\sffamily

\thispagestyle{plain}{
\rhead[]{}
\lhead[]{}
%\markboth{I}{I}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\cfoot[]{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}}

\rhead[]{\thechapter. \leftmark}
\lhead[\thechapter. \rightmark]{}
\markboth{I}{I}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\cfoot[]{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\section{M}
\end{document}
```

By doing so I get a headrule with "I" on the right side and I just want this last 2 things (headrule and "I") to not appear.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just fragments that have to be glued together

Comment: We've had this question before - the first page of a `\chapter` usually issues the `plain` page style. You've redefined this rather than creating a new one and tapping into `\chapter`. Either way, this is discussed and solved in [`fancyhdr` does not apply same header/footer on chapter and non-chapter pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117328/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? I've defined a special `chapterfirstpage` style that deletes the headrule and all footers for the chapter start page, by replacing `\thispagestyle{plain}` with `\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \rfoot{\thepage}%
}


\usepackage{afterpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}



\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace{-10\p@}
    \rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\markboth{}{}   
\chapter{In}

\sffamily

\section{M}
\blindtext[10]

\chapter{Two}
\section{Foo}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Note: `vmargin` has some issues and should be replaced with `geometry`, most likely.

I also incorporated the `\rule...` in the chapter heading `\@makechapterhead` command.

[image]

Comment: It is almost perfect. but I would also like to insert the page number as  footnote on the right side

Comment: @Leila: See the update please. I added `\rfoot{\thepage}` in `chapterfirstpage` style