# Subdividing body in three parts and drawing line to show division

Tags: subdividing, line, body

I would like to have a page display like this one :

[image]

[n] being the page number. I won't need to write anything in the right and bottom part. (I just need those spaces to put handwritten comments). Chapter page and the table of content should have a classic display.

For now, I have this code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{Comments : }
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rule{\footrulewidth}{.5in} Keys Words : }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
        \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
        \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\footrulewidth}}
        \vskip\footruleskip}}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=.5in, right=1.5in, bottom=2.5in, top=.5in}


\hspace{\fill}\rule{\footrulewidth}{575pt}

\end{document}
```

And it's output this :

[image]

Top-right corner is offset and the page number is also at the wrong place. I think I need to rework completely the code to overcome those difficulties, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to write only by hand in the right and bottom part, I thought your layout could be created easily with `tikz`, as a page background.

I also added these two lines of code from [a Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117334/101651) to make the chapter first page like the others:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=.5in, right=2in, bottom=2.5in, top=.5in, marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[L]{Comments:}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% the following two lines of code are from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117334/101651
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\usepackage{mwe}% for testing purpose only

\begin{document}
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{% 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            % horizontal line
            \draw[line width=1pt] (0,.214\paperheight) -- (\paperwidth,.214\paperheight);
            % vertical line
            \draw[line width=1pt] (.8\paperwidth,\paperheight) -- (.8\paperwidth,.214\paperheight);
            % page number at the very bottom
            \node[text width=4em, align=right] at (.93\paperwidth,.03\paperheight) {\thepage};
            % "Key Words:" at the very top
            \node at (.88\paperwidth,.97\paperheight) {Keys Words:};
        \end{tikzpicture}}}
    % The following lines are for testing purpose only
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{This is for testing purpose only}
    \section{Some text with a footnote}
    \blindtext\footnote{A test footnote.} 
    \blindtext[3]
    \section{Some text without footnotes}
    \blindtext
    \chapter{Just to show the page numbering}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

And here are some sample pages:

[image] 
[image]
[image]