# Header not appearing for some unnumbered chapters in report class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have two unnumbered chapters in my document (`report` class). The Introduction which is the second chapter in the whole document and the Conclusion which is the penultimate one (just before the Bibliography).

While the same line of code works for the penultimate chapter, making its header appear properly on top the page, it has no effect on the Introduction chapter, leaving it without a header.
This is my code so far:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6 in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
% -------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[l]{\fontsize{6} \ifnum\value{chapter}>0  \nouppercase{\rightmark} \fi}
\cfoot{ \thepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Abstract}%
FOO 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}%
\chapter*{Introduction}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} \markboth{}{Introduction}
BAR
\chapter*{Concluding Remarks}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Conclusion}\markboth{}{Summary and Conclusion}
TEXT
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`fancyhdr` does not apply same header/footer on chapter and non-chapter pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117328/5764)

Comment: @Werner - The OP's code issues go deeper than "just" not knowing how to modify the `plain` page style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that the instruction

```
\fontsize{6}
```

is syntactically invalid: `\fontsize` takes two arguments, not one. It should probably be

```
\fontsize{6}{7.5}\selectfont
```

Usually, the second argument of `\fontsize` is chosen to be 20% to 25% larger than the first.

A secondary issue is that the `report` document class uses the `plain` page style for pages that contain chapter-level headers. To override this, in view of the fact that you use the `fancyhdr` package, you should follow the instructions in section 7 of the package's user guide, i.e., use the `\fancypagestyle` macro to redefine the `plain` page style. That's what's done in the following example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in,9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[l]{%
    \fontsize{6}{7.5}\selectfont%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\nouppercase{\rightmark}\fi}
\cfoot{\thepage}

% redefine 'plain' page style to match 'fancy' style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[l]{%
    \fontsize{6}{7.5}\selectfont%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\nouppercase{\rightmark}\fi}
\cfoot{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\markboth{}{Abstract}
FOO 

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
\markboth{}{Introduction}
BAR

\chapter*{Concluding Remarks}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}\markboth{}{Summary and Conclusion}
TEXT

\end{document}
```