# Defining a New \pagestyle Using Fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

Using the **fancyhdr** package, the code below does exactly what I want for my headers and footers.  I use the **empty** pagestyle, redefine the **plain** pagestyle, and define a **fancy** pagestyle.

There is something about the way you define the **fancy** pagestyle that bothers me (no brackets indicating the beginning and end of the definition).  So, as an experiment, I used **\fancypagestyle** to define a **MyFancy** pagestyle that is identical to the **fancy** pagestyle.  From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117328/fancyhdr-does-not-apply-same-header-footer-on-chapter-and-non-chapter-pages) answer, I thought I was on the right track.

However, in the **\frontmatter** section below, if you comment out **\pagestyle{fancy}** and uncomment **\pagestyle{MyFancy}**, the results are different.  In the **\mainmatter**, you no longer get the chapter information where it was expected to be in the footer (i.e., it was expected to be on all non-empty pages that were not the first page of a chapter).  No doubt I am missing something obvious, but I am stumped.

Question: What changed are needed to my code so I can use the **MyFancy** pagestyle as a replacement for the **fancy** pagestyle?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Some Book Name}
\author{Henry A. Smith}

\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}                             
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}     
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}   
\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {Page \thepage}
\makeatletter\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\if@mainmatter \leftmark\fi}\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \fancyhf{}           
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}    
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}   
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE] {Page \thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{MyFancy}{%              
    \fancyhf{}%                            
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%    
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}%
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE] {Page \thepage}%
    \makeatletter\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\if@mainmatter \leftmark\fi}\makeatother}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
Copyright 2018, Henry A. Smith
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\pagestyle{fancy}    % COMMENT THIS OUT
%\pagestyle{MyFancy} % UNCOMMENT THIS
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1-5]

\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\backmatter
\chapter{BackMatter Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to fancyhdr `\makeatletter\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\if@mainmatter \leftmark\fi}\makeatother}` can not work, move the `\make...` out of the argument and just have one `\makeatletter` and one `\makeatother` around all the definitions that need `@` in your preamble

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I followed your advice. That is all it took!  I learned something new.  Make an answer and I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unrelated to `fancyhdr`

```
{\makeatletter\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\if@mainmatter \leftmark\fi}\makeatother}
```

can not work, move the `\make...` out of the argument and just have one `\makeatletter` and one `\makeatother` around all the definitions that need `@` in your preamble.

The reason it can not work is the same as the reason `\verb` does not work in an argument of another command. As you have it the argument is scanned while `@` is not a letter so the argument is the same as

```
{\makeatletter\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\if @mainmatter \leftmark\fi}\makeatother}
```

the `\makeatletter` is not executed until this argument is *used* and by then it is too late catcode changes have no effect on already tokenised text, they just affect the tokens that are created when characters are read from a file.