# Bibliography with incorrect page number place

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, book-class

Hello I'm new using book class an I have problem adapting the format of thesis to this class, I need the page number on the upper right corner in the main body of the work and in the bibliography pages, also the preliminaries have another format of page numbering, but the first page  of the bibliography have the number in the lower central part of the page, if anyone help me with this issue I really I really appreciate it . Thank you :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}     % Tipo de documento y otras especificaciones
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % Para escribir tildes y eñes
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}                   % Para que los títulos de figuras, tablas y otros estén en español
%\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}                   % Cambiar nombre a tablas
%\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}        % Cambiar nombre a lista de tablas
\usepackage{bold-extra} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=18mm,right=18mm,top=21mm,bottom=21mm} % Tamaño del área de escritura de la página
\usepackage{amsmath}      % Los paquetes ams son desarrollados por la American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amsfonts}     % y mejoran la escritura de fórmulas y símbolos matemáticos.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}     % Para insertar gráficas
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}  % Para colocar varias figuras
%\usepackage{unitsdef}    % Para la presentación correcta de unidades
%\renewcommand{\unitvaluesep}{\hspace*{4pt}}    % Redimensionamiento del espacio entre magnitud y unidad
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=green]{hyperref}     % Para insertar hipervínculos y marcadores
\usepackage{float}      % Para ubicar las tablas y figuras justo después del texto
\usepackage{booktabs}   % Para hacer tablas más estilizadas
\batchmode

%\pagestyle{plain}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % Para manejar los encabezados y pies de página
%\pagestyle{fancy}      % Contenido de los encabezados y pies de pagina







\begin{document}




\pagestyle{empty} %oculta el numero de pagina
\include{portada}

\pagenumbering{roman}
% Páginas preliminares: empieza en página 2, pagestyle 'frontmatter' definido en gaoThesis
%\frontmatter
%\setcounter{page}{2}
%\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{frontmatter}
%\pagestyle{frontmatter}

\newgeometry{left=35mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\setcounter{page}{2}
\include{preliminares}
%\pagestyle{main}




\newgeometry{left=35mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
%\pagestyle{plain} %Permite aparecer el numero de pagina en todas las paginas

%


%\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%\pagestyle{headings}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}


\include{intro}




%\bibliographystyle{apsrmp}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{plain}



%%%%%  Here is the bibfile
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}


\bibliography{mybibfile.bib} 



\end{document}
```

Here is the result I need the fancy style in all pages of the bibliography. Thank you !!!

[image]

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117328/fancyhdr-does-not-apply-same-header-footer-on-chapter-and-non-chapter-pages). Solution: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}`

Comment: thank you but with this solution the problem is the preview, this package changes all the document including the abstract  index and all the preview

Comment: I tried to use the command \pagestyle{plain} in the preliminaries but doesn´t work