# Fancy style, textheight change from chapter to chapter

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr, height

I create my own header and footer style with the package `fancyhdr`, and I want it also on the chapter pages. I used the solution in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117328/fancyhdr-does-not-apply-same-header-footer-on-chapter-and-non-chapter-pages). Also, as my style needed to change the spacing between the header and the text, I redefined the `headsep` and `textheight` size, according to [the package documentation](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) (page 6).

For the "normal" parts, it's fine, all dimensions are like I defined. For the chapter pages, the `textheight` I set is not taken into account. And for the first one, the text fill the page in a shape that is fine. But for the second chapter, the text height seems to be the one defined in `MyStyle`, and it split the text on a new page.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titletoc}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Foo}
  \lfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
  \renewcommand{\headsep}{5cm}
  \renewcommand{\textheight}{19cm}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Foo}
  \lfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
  \renewcommand{\headsep}{0cm}
  \renewcommand{\textheight}{99cm} % It seems it has no effect
}

%generates filler text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Alph{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

  \pagestyle{MyStyle}

  \chapter{My chapter 1}
    \Blindtext[3][2]

  \section{Section 1}

    \subsection{SubSec 1.1}

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.1.A}
        \label{sss1A}
        \blindtext

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.1.B}
        \label{sss1B}
        \blindtext

    \subsection{SubSec 1.2}

  \section{Section 2}

    \subsection{SubSec 2.1}

    \subsection{SubSec 2.2}

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 2.2.A}
        \label{sss2A}
        \blindtext

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 2.2.B}
        \label{sss2B}
        \blindtext

  \section{Section 3}

    \ref{sss1A} and \ref{sss2B} refer to sections 1.1.A and 2.2.B. But as it
    is, we could think they refer to two successive sections.

  \chapter{My chapter 2}
  \Blindtext[3][2]

\end{document}
```

I really does not understand this problem. Did I miss something ? Is it a bug ? ...

Comment: Does fancyhdr have different commands for odd vs even pages?

Comment: @gnucchi I don't know. But I added more text in the different sections, now the second chapter is on an odd page (as the first one), and the problem is still here

Comment: At best, you are trying to change the page geometry in the middle of a page (when \chapter calls \thispagestyle{plain}).  My advice is, don't do that!  You can change \headrulewidth because it is part of the header and isn't added until after the page is complete.  Instead set \headsep in geometry permanently and modify \chapter to overlap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the `etoolbox` package to modify `\@makechapterhead` to overlap the `\headsep` area.  It also removes the extra 50pt gap normally added.

BTW, while `\headrulewidth` is a macro, `\headsep` and `\textheight` are dimen registers and should be set using `\setlength`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=7cm, headsep=5cm,  bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}% top includes headsep

\usepackage{titletoc}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-5cm}}{}{Error}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Foo}
  \lfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Foo}
  \lfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}

%generates filler text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Alph{subsubsection}}

\pagestyle{MyStyle}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{My chapter 1}

    \the\headsep

    \the\textheight

    \Blindtext[3][2]

  \section{Section 1}

    \subsection{SubSec 1.1}

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.1.A}
        \label{sss1A}
        \blindtext

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.1.B}
        \label{sss1B}
        \blindtext

    \subsection{SubSec 1.2}

  \section{Section 2}

    \subsection{SubSec 2.1}

    \subsection{SubSec 2.2}

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 2.2.A}
        \label{sss2A}
        \blindtext

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 2.2.B}
        \label{sss2B}
        \blindtext

  \section{Section 3}

    \ref{sss1A} and \ref{sss2B} refer to sections 1.1.A and 2.2.B. But as it
    is, we could think they refer to two successive sections.

    \the\headsep

    \the\textheight

  \chapter{My chapter 2}

    \the\headsep

    \the\textheight

  \Blindtext[3][2]

\end{document}
```

---

This version places the first line of text (after the chapter title) inside the text area.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=7cm, headsep=5cm,  bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}% top includes headsep

\usepackage{titletoc}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}% not sure where the extra ilne comes from
  \noindent\raisebox{0pt}[0pt]{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Foo}
  \lfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Foo}
  \lfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}

%generates filler text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Alph{subsubsection}}

\pagestyle{MyStyle}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{My chapter 1}

    \Blindtext[3][2]

  \section{Section 1}

    \subsection{SubSec 1.1}

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.1.A}
        \label{sss1A}
        \blindtext

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.1.B}
        \label{sss1B}
        \blindtext

    \subsection{SubSec 1.2}

  \section{Section 2}

    \subsection{SubSec 2.1}

    \subsection{SubSec 2.2}

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 2.2.A}
        \label{sss2A}
        \blindtext

      \subsubsection{SubSubSec 2.2.B}
        \label{sss2B}
        \blindtext

  \section{Section 3}

    \ref{sss1A} and \ref{sss2B} refer to sections 1.1.A and 2.2.B. But as it
    is, we could think they refer to two successive sections.

  \chapter{My chapter 2}

  \Blindtext[3][2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for the sample I made, but not for my real document. For it, the `etoolbox` package has no effect! And I can't find out why

Comment: \chapter (and \@makechapterhead) is different for different document classes.  Some  packages (like titlesec)  replace or modify \chapter.  OTOH, if you are loading titlesec, you can use that to change the top margin.

Comment: The problem was the `sectsty` package. I just change the loading order (`sectsty` first). And the first version of your answer works (I saw you edited after :s). But one more question. Do you know how to make one specific page (the one with the toc or the lof) use the plain style. Just adding `\pagestyle{plain}` does not work. Thanks

Comment: I also tried your second solution, and there is a little problem with it. I use the `sectsty` to change the color of the sections and chapters titles (`\chapterfont{\color{blue}}`). And the color is gone for the chapters with your second solution. I can have it again by adding `\color{}` before the `\ifnum`. But this way, we define the section, subsection,... color at a place, and the chapter color at an other place. But anyway, your first solution works ;)

Comment: I tried `pagestyle{plain}` and `\thispagestyle{plain}` with both `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`, and it changed nothing

Comment: IIRC, the TOC and LOF use \thispagestyle{plain} automatically (depending on the document class).  They do not however use \@makechapterhead, but rather use \@makeschapterhead.

Comment: :s I can't tell you

Comment: You can use \patchcmd on \@makeschapterhead.  It also contains \vspace*{50\p@}.

Comment: \o/ it works, thanks a lot