# Change page number position starting chapter

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like to change the position of the page number on all the pages include the first page of a chapter.
I use `fancyhdr` package and this is my code:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\rmfamily\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\rmfamily\thechapter\ \nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
```

But the position of the page number is correct in all the pages except the page where the chapter start. In the first page of chapter the page number is centered and in the other pages it is alternated. How can I resolve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fancyhdr does not apply same header/footer on chapter and non-chapter pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117328/fancyhdr-does-not-apply-same-header-footer-on-chapter-and-non-chapter-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first page of each chapter in the standard LaTeX document classes use page style `plain`. So you have to redefine the `plain` page style to have the same footer as the `fancy` page style.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\rmfamily\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\rmfamily\thechapter\ \nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```