# First chapter title closer to header than other chapters

Tags: header-footer, chapters, alignment, report

I'm trying to create a report-style document where the page headers are present also in the chapters pages.
I managed to to it using this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117334) reply. This seems to work in all chapters, but in the first one the title is much closer to the header than in the others (see screenshot comparison).

[image: Current alignment of chapters titles]

I'd like to obtain something like the following image, where the chapter titles are aligned and at the same distance from the header.

[image: Expected alignment of chapters titles]

In the document preamble (see below) I changed a bit I had to change the standard chapter page raising the chapter title in order to make more space for the test I want to have on the same page, but this should be equal for all chapters.
In fact, reducing YY in `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-YYpt}{10pt}` does move the titles further away from the header line, but it does not change the fact the distance is different in the chapter called "Abstract" and the other.

I guess that potentially I could edit the title of only chapter 1 following something like this (https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20676), but I guess there should be a cleaner solution.

What could be the cause of this and how can I solve it?
Thank you in advance for the help!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\small \textit{head line1 \\ head line 2}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}



\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large}
% this alters "before" spacing (the second length argument) to 0
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
%%===================================
\begin{document}
    \cleardoublepage
    \include{font}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \emergencystretch 3em
    \raggedbottom
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}  
    \lipsum[1]
    \cleardoublepage
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{Chapt 2 title}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please edit your code to remove unnecessary packages please, `amsmath` is likely not required to troubleshoot this issue for example, and make it compile so we can copy, paste and run it ? `:)`

Comment: Thanks  @JamesT! I've made a self-contained example removing most packages. Now it should be run by anyone without any problems. Now the problem appears in the "Abstract" chapter

Comment: Have you tried changing `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{10pt}` to `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt}`? That appears to work in your code. Other then that, could you put pictures of how your code (that you have put in the question, not the main document) looks and what you want to change as it does not produce the images you have attached in your question

Comment: Reducing that moves the titles further away from the horizontal header line, but does not change the fact that "Abstract" is closer to it than the title of the other chapter. I've edited the questions with the updated images and specifying the current situation and the expected outcome