# Add page numbers in different positions in different pages

Tags: page-numbering

My requirement is to have roman page numbers in the top center of the page for the first few pages and then for the remainder of the pages to have arabic numbers in the bottom center. How do I achieve this?

I tried to use `fancyhdr` but it does not seem to work with the `\input` command. Any suggestions how to do this? MWE below (tried using `fancyhdr` on this):

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
 
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}\label{introduction}
\input{1-introduction}

\chapter{LITERATURE REVIEW}\label{lit-review}
\input{2-literature}

\end{document}
```

#### What I want to achieve:

[image]

**Note: I am using a cls file. The first 6 pages needed to be numbered in roman and stated above, the remainder in arabic.**

Comment: You probably need to change the pagestyle.

Comment: `fancyhdr` is independent of using `\input`. Maybe you've not recognized, that [the page with `\chapter` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117328/277964) See the `fancyhdr` manual for information about also changing this page style. If I'm wrong, please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried (without using `\input`). BTW: To have a roman numbered front matter, IMHO using class `book` and commands `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` could be a good idea.