# How make the footer under the pages of the new chapters?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, chapter-page

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{a4paper,hmargin=1.25in,vmargin=1in}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.6pt}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let \bm=\relax}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{Eureka! Journal Entry}}
\fancyfoot[C]{March 10, 2024}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Some Rights Reserved.}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\SetWatermarkText{\shortstack{\textsc{Eureka!}}}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.75}
\SetWatermarkScale{7.5}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\frontmatter

\chapter*{\Huge \center Eureka!}
\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Preface}

Preface...

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Topics in Elementary Mathematics}
Introduction to Topics in Elementary Mathematics...
\newpage
Currently, there are no submissions in this section.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

So here goes the problem, in those pages with the chapter number, the footer doesn't work as it normally would. I want the footer to work on those pages, BUT not the header. I have no idea how to do it, please help me out.

Plus, there's another minor issue: the header normally works in the style of "Chapter 2. Elementary Mathematics Contests", but on the content page, it still remains the style of default, which is "CONTENT". How can I change it to "Content"?

Comment: There is no `\tableofcontents` in your MWE, nor is there any `\chapter`. Please supply us with some "content" between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` so we can better see the issue.

Comment: In terms of the header/footer issue, the "culprit" is the fact that on opening pages of chapters, a different page style is used. The standard definition of `\chapter` includes issuing `\thispagestyle{plain}`. So you just need to redefine what `plain` looks like. See, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117328

Comment: @WillieWong I've added some of the contents to it: `\tableofcontents` and `\chapter` lines. Please check it again.

Comment: For a stab at what is probably your second problem: where you have `\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\leftmark}}`, replace `\rightmark` by `\nouppercase{\rightmark}` ad similarly for `\leftmark`. The LaTeX `book` class hardcodes `\MakeUpperCase` into the `\markboth` when issuing `\tableofcontents`, you can undo it with `\nouppercase`.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks a lot for solving my problem. Have a good day!

Comment: General info: The book design term, for having a page number at the bottom of a new chapter, without printed header, is "drop folio." If your layout has a footer, no problem, just use a page style there, as already explained by others. But if your layout has only a header, then you must create a one-page temporary footer there. TeX can do that. Search for "drop folio" and see what results. Do not confuse this with "drop cap."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the starting chapter pages, the `book` class uses the `plain` page style, so you just need to redefine it, which `fancyhdr` allows through `\fancypagestyle`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  hmargin=1.25in,
  vmargin=1in,
  headheight=13.6pt, % as suggested by fancyhdr
}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clear all fields
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{Eureka! Journal Entry}}
\fancyfoot[C]{March 10, 2024}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Some Rights Reserved.}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\textit{Eureka! Journal Entry}}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{March 10, 2024}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Some Rights Reserved.}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}
  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Eureka!}

\chapter{Preface}

Preface...

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Topics in Elementary Mathematics}
Introduction to Topics in Elementary Mathematics...
\newpage
Currently, there are no submissions in this section.

\end{document}
```

I removed all packages unnecessary for the example, except for `geometry` in order to point out that you need to set the `headheight`.

[image]

I also used `\chapter` and not `\chapter*` in the front matter, so you get those chapters in the table of contents. *Don't use* formatting declarations in a chapter title, unless you want `\Huge` also in the table of contents (which I don't think you do). If you *really* need the `\Huge` chapter title, do

```
\chapter[Eureka!]{\Huge Eureka!}
```